# Passing JSON to Google custom function in Sheets

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to use an Apps Script to create a custom function in Google Sheets. The function is meant to generate a HIIT/Tabata workout plan based on entered percentages for types of exercises (upper body, lower body and core; then various subtypes such as upper body > weights, upper body > pushup variations, etc.). There's a worksheet in my Google sheet with the exercises and tags in columns.

I'm still working on the function, but I'm having an issue executing it. When I try to input something like the following into a Sheets cell to run the function, I get a "Formula parse error" with no further info:

=WPLAN(30, 5, [{workoutType: "Lower Body", percentage: 60, tagPercentages: [{tag: "squats", percentage: 60}, {tag: "lowimpact", percentage: 40}]}, {workoutType: "Upper Body", percentage: 40, tagPercentages: [{tag: "pushups", percentage: 50}, {tag: "weights", percentage: 50}]}])

I also tried the following, with the same result:

=WPLAN(30, 5, "[{"workoutType": "Lower Body", "percentage": 60, "tagPercentages": [{"tag": "squats", "percentage": 60}, {"tag": "lowimpact", "percentage": 40}]}, {"workoutType": "Upper Body", "percentage": 40, "tagPercentages": [{"tag": "pushups", "percentage": 50}, {"tag": "weights", "percentage": 50}]}]")

Can Sheets accept JSON as a function parameter? I can make the function execute without the error if I enter:

=WPLAN(30, 5,workoutType)

Though of course the function itself fails because the input is wrong. Is there a workaround that will let me pass the JSON in?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, for exmaple, as a simple approach, how about putting `[{"workoutType": "Lower Body", "percentage": 60, "tagPercentages": [{"tag": "squats", "percentage": 60}, {"tag": "lowimpact", "percentage": 40}]}, {"workoutType": "Upper Body", "percentage": 40, "tagPercentages": [{"tag": "pushups", "percentage": 50}, {"tag": "weights", "percentage": 50}]}]` into cell "A1", putting a custom function of `=WPLAN(30, 5, A1)` into cell "A2"? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass JSON to a custom function

```
function PASSINGJSON(s) {
  let obj = JSON.parse(s);
  return Object.keys(obj);
}
```

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 |
| 2 | {"one":1,"two":2,"three":3,"four":4} | one |
| 3 |  | two |
| 4 |  | three |
| 5 |  | four |

The formula in B2:

```
=PASSINGJSON(A2)
```

With the same formula but a slightly different function:

```
function PASSINGJSON(s) {
  let obj = JSON.parse(s);
  return Object.keys(obj).map(k => [k,obj[k]]);
}
```

A little bit different output:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 |  |
| 2 | {"one":1,"two":2,"three":3,"four":4,"five":5} | one | 1 |
| 3 |  | two | 2 |
| 4 |  | three | 3 |
| 5 |  | four | 4 |
| 6 |  | five | 5 |